# Is there a way to tell SSH which key to select from an agent, without referring to the public/private key files?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

### Context

I have multiple SSH keypairs. Currently I handle that by having a collection of keys in `~/.ssh` (password-protected of course), and in `~/.ssh/config` I have `Host` sections with the right `IdentityFile` for each one, and use `AddKeysToAgent` to cache the keys for a while after I unlock them.

I synchronise my `~/.ssh/config` file across multiple machines along with the rest of my dotfiles (in a git repostitory), but I wanted to avoid the private keys ever "moving", so for now I just generate keypairs separately on each machine but store them in the same paths, so the synchronised `IdentifyFile` configuration still picks them up. Then it's just a matter of separately authorizing the keys from all of my machines on the hosts I will need to log in to.

### The problem

I'm considering simplifying this setup by storing my SSH keys in my password manager, which has a feature for automatically adding them to a running `ssh-agent`. Then the keys would live in my password database, which I already have a synchronisation solution for (separately from my gitted dotfiles obviously!), and I wouldn't need to generate keypairs on every machine (although with the disadvantage of no longer being able to revoke an individual machine's keys).

However, then I would have no key files to refer to in the `IdentifyFile` configuration to specify which key to use for each host. Is there a solution that avoids this? I'd hoped there would be a way to identify the key based on the `comment`, or something.

### Non-solutions

I am aware that I can use the **public** key files in `IdentityFile` for SSH to select the key from the agent, even if the **private** key doesn't exist in a file. Theoretically I could put those in my dotfiles repostitory, but I don't like synchronising the public and private halves of my keys by separate mechanisms (they could end up out of sync and completely unusable in certain circumstances, and a change in which keys I have that are valid is different and conceptually not synchronised with changes in my *configuration*; e.g. if I roll back to an older version of my dotfiles configuration I still need my current ssh keys, not the ones I was using when I made that dotfiles commit). So if that's the only solution, I will probably not bother to switch my process at all.

I also can't rely on letting SSH try all the keys in the agent; I don't think I have so many that I will regularly hit the "too many failed authentication attempts" issue, but I do need to access multiple separate GitHub accounts, and SSH access to GitHub identifies your account by which key you use. So when it can try them all it will often find one that *does* authenticate (so git/SSH will stop trying more keys), but to the wrong account (so my attempted action fails).

### TLDR

Is there any alternative way to get SSH to select the right key, or must I have a file to point to using `IdentityFile`/`-i`?